# Looping over data to create "dynamic routes" in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I have a question to react-router-dom. Is it possible to do something like that?

I use React-Bootstrap so there some wrappers/wrapper components that could be the problem.

I try to create a dynamic route loop:

```
import React from "react"
import {products} from "../data/Products"
import {Route} from "react-router-dom"
import {DetailedProduct} from "../components/DetailedProduct"

export const ProductRoutesGenerator = () => {
    return (
        products.map((product => {
            return (
                <Route exact path={product.productName} component={DetailedProduct(product)}/>
            )
        })
    ))
}
```

and the Component should be created like that:

```
import {Container} from "react-bootstrap"

export const DetailedProduct = (props) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <h1>{props.productName}</h1>
            <h3>{props.productDescription}</h3>
            <h5>{props.productPrice}</h5>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance :-)

Edit:
The index.js file look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './App'
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals'
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"

ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
              <BrowserRouter>
                    <App/>
              </BrowserRouter>
      </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
```

I just wrapped the BrowserRouter over the App. Beside that all code should be default from the create react command.

products is a JavaScript object for testing it looks like this:

```
export const products = [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "productName": "testProduct0",
    "productDescription": "testDescription",
    "productPrice": 10
  }
,
  {
    "id": "1",
    "productName": "testProduct1",
    "productDescription": "testDescription",
    "productPrice": 20
  }
...
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
          <div>
              <h1>
                  {products[1].productName}
              </h1>
          </div>
              <BrowserRouter>
                    <App/>
              </BrowserRouter>
      </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

renders me my product name so yes i get the value before BrowserRouter is called.

Comment: Did you use any `Router` or `Switch` in your code?

Comment: Does `products` have value on the first render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React from "react"
import {products} from "../data/Products"
import {Route} from "react-router-dom"
import {DetailedProduct} from "../components/DetailedProduct";

export const ProductRoutesGenerator = () => {
    return (
            products.map((product) => {
                return (
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path={'/' + product.productName}
                        key={product.id}
                        children={ <DetailedProduct product={product}/> } />
                )
            })
    )
}
```

This was a journey! So I managed to render a dynamic component and link a dynamic route to it.

I missed two things. The '/' before the `product.productName` and the `children={}` in the Route.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { products } from "../data/Products";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { DetailedProduct } from "../components/DetailedProduct";

export const ProductRoutesGenerator = () => {
  return products.map((product, index) => {
    return (
      <Route
        exact
        path={product.productName}
        key={index}
        component={<DetailedProduct product={product} />}
      />
    );
  });
};

//=====================

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

export const DetailedProduct = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>{product.productName}</h1>
      <h3>{product.productDescription}</h3>
      <h5>{product.productPrice}</h5>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: It dont work. I know that because i have a testcomponent that is linked to the button of product 2. So when i click on the button of product 2 it renders my testcomponent but all other buttons only change the url to /productX and not render any component.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `Switch` to encapsulate the routes. This should fix the problem:

```
import React from "react"
import {products} from "../data/Products"
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"
import {DetailedProduct} from "../components/DetailedProduct"

export const ProductRoutesGenerator = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            {products.map((product) => {
                return (
                    <Route
                        exact
                        key={product.id}
                        path={product.productName}
                    >
                        <DetailedProduct {...product} />
                    </Route>
                )
            })}
        <Switch>
    )
}
```

Comment: I changed my answer, there was something wrong I think with the `component` prop in the route. Can you try it?

Comment: i will try sure

Comment: I tried and it dont work. I also tried something but it seems it is impossible to create something like a route generator even when the code is executed and no error are thrown. It just link me to a empty site :/

Comment: Hmm usually I set my paths as `/something`. Did you try also adding the slash?

Comment: ```<Route exact path={"/testProduct2"} component={testComp}/>
            <ProductRoutesGenerator/>```

the testComponent get rendered when i click the button of testProduct2

but the other routes from the "generator" dont trigger. Maybe they dont even exist.

Comment: Can you please provide a codepen or something similar to properly help on this?